# Mac file com.apple.bluetooth.plist missing

Tags: mac, bluetooth

I have an issue with my iMac not connecting to bluetooth or airdrop etc.hardware is turned off and I cannot turn it back on, all usual methods of forcing the Mac to update and replace missing files have failed.
Ive narrowed the issue down to the bluetooth system files missing:
com.apple.bluetooth.plist actually all of the plist bluetooth files are missing from /libary/preferences and a full search of the Mac - nowhere to be found.

I cannotupdate any further and attempts to roll back to a previous iOS fails, so I am looking at how I can manually replace/add the missing files

any thoughts?

thanks

Comment: I think the missing preferences plist files is a symptom, not a root cause. For example, if your Bluetooth hardware is failing so the Bluetooth software is never loading, you'll never have a chance to set any non-default Bluetooth settings that would need to be stored in a preferences plist, so the file will never be created. Have you run Apple Diagnostics (formerly Apple Hardware Test) to make sure your Bluetooth hardware is okay?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the advice
Apple diagnostic picks up no issues at all. 
This happened after an upgrade to Monterey, I’ve updated to Sonoma and it’s still the same.

Comment: I have tried an external usb bluetooth dongle, that isn't working either, onboard blue tooth in System - bluetooth controller is showing up like this  Bluetooth Controller:
  Address: NULL
  State: Off
  Chipset: BCM_4350C2
  Discoverable: Off
  Firmware Version: v0 c0
  Supported Devices: 0x392039 < HFP AVRCP A2DP HID Braille LEA AACP GATT SerialPort >
  Transport: USB
  Vendor ID: 0x004C (Apple)